# Is there a way to make your program wait untill a button is pressed android studio?

Tags: java, android, button, listener

currently I am trying to populate 3 string arrays using 3 edittext fields in which the user will enter some information. currently I am doing the following:

```
String[] a,b,c = new String[x];
int i = 0
Button Submit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_form);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        x = intent.getIntExtra("x", 0);

        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(i<x) {
                    a[i] =findViewById(R.id.field1).getText().toString();
                    b[i] =findViewById(R.id.field2).getText().toString();
                    c[i] =findViewById(R.id.field3).getText().toString();   
             ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.field1)).getText().clear();
             ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.field2)).getText().clear();
             ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.field3)).getText().clear();
             i++;  
             }else{
             Intent intent = new Intent(form.this, compact.class);
                        intent.putExtra(Strings)
      }
}
```

My code is currently stuck in the if statement and it is unable to proceed to the else case and send the data, please let me know what I need to do in order to fix it or if there is a different approach I should use.

Basically what I am trying to do is allow the user to enter data into x number of forms.

Thanks, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need the loop at all? Just remove the loop and increment the counter as normal, with an extra check for `i < x` if necessary.

Comment: do you mean use an if statement instead of the while loop? if yes then it would run into the same problem because it will not be able to pause, I also need some kind of loop to make sure the arrays have correct entries.

Comment: But if you're wanting the loop to 'pause' until the next input (which isn't actually possible), it's not running as a loop anyway? You might as well just handle each click? I think you need to reconsider your logic or maybe make it clear what kind of execution you want from your code.

Comment: So the idea is basically to generate x number of input forms for the user and allow the user to fill in these forms individually

Comment: Right, I still don't see the need for the loop. Surely every time you click the button, you want to store the current inputs, clear the fields and increment `i`. You just don't need the loop.

Comment: I tried replacing the while loop with an if statement but it just proceeds after 1 form execution, There is not opportunity for the second form to appear

Comment: What are you referring to with "[forms appearing]"? I presumed you meant clearing the fields to allow more input? If so I am not sure why it would only run once if the button was clicked twice.

Comment: My mistake by forms appearing I meant the clearing of fields and allowing the user to input new details. also I misunderstood what you meant by if statement. I have now implemented it in a simple 

`If(i<x){`
`Clear form;`
`i++;`
`}else{`
`proceed to the next activity`
`}`
but the code keeps running and it is unable to break the if statement, I have declared i in the class section as 0 so it should not be stuck in an inf loop, what exactly is happening?

Comment: So did that solve your problem?

Comment: Yes but it is now unable to break the if statement and it is stuck in a loop

Comment: My guess is because the return type of the listener is void, so I think it is unable to increment i therefore it is stuck in a loop, is there any way to fix this?

Comment: If there's no loop, I don't understand how it can be stuck in one. Maybe [edit] your question with the updated code?

Comment: Your code seems correct to me, although you're not using the intent anywhere? Are you sure that `x` is the correct value? Maybe try using a constant instead to check?

Comment: Hey it was my fault I forgot to start the next activity which I had temporarily commented out for debugging purposes. The code works not. Thank You for your assistance Henry